# Got different results using SEC EDGAR API and Seeking Alpha

Tags: programming, fundamentals, sec

I am trying to get the same Depreciation and Amortization (Total) we can get for AAPL on Seeking Alpha and QuickFS for instance. Here is what is their values:

[image]

However, what I am getting using the SEC EDGAR API is this: [image]

Those values are from the DepreciationAmortizationAndAccretionNet tag. I got mostly the same value except for the years 2018 to 2023 where I got NaN. It is not an error, this is really what I got from the SEC API.

How can I get the same values from the SEC API?